# Connect multiple tables in Access

Tags: database, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I want to connect multiple tables in Access. I have a main table and then multiple smaller tables that I would like to connect. Each row in the main table belongs to one entire sub-table. I would like to have small + appear next to each row in the main table and showing the sub-tables upon clicking on the +.

I tried this via relationships but it only works for the first row (perfectly) but not for any other rows. When clicking on the other rows, they are empty and no sub-table is opening up.

Any ideas?

Comment: It sounds like you need to rethink your table design. Rather than having multiple sub-tables, have a single table, with a foreign key that relates to the primary key in the main table.

Comment: Access simply can't have multiple subtables in table view. If you have multiple related tables, you need to use forms

Answer (score 0):

Per the comments if you must do this here is an example:

example main table and sub tables

[image]

example form created from the main table using the create form wizard and selecting tabular to get a better looking starting form:

[image]

note I added an unbound button to the details section and that button gets replicated for each row of data.  I will show two ways of setting up the button to open the correct form.

put the form in design mode open the button's properties and open the onclick event.  you can do this with the macro language but I show the code:

```
Private Sub openButton_Click()
'each button the detail section creates has access to the data or controls in the buttons row
DoCmd.OpenTable Me.subTableName 'if form use .OpenForm
'DoCmd.Close acForm, "mainForm"  'if want to close main form
'OpenTable (MainID)
End Sub
```

if the logic behind opening the form gets complicated I suggest abstracting the logic to a function.  here use OpenTable instead and add the Public OpenTable function inside a code module.

```
Public Function OpenTable(tableID As Long) As Boolean 'function allows the option checking the return value to test if OpenTable worked
Select Case tableID
Case 1
DoCmd.OpenTable "subTable1"
Case 2
DoCmd.OpenTable "subTable2"
Case 3
DoCmd.OpenTable "subTable3"
End Select
OpenTable = True
End Function
```

Note: you could expand the form's header and show the mainTable as a subform in that header.  Then you could add a button next to each row in that subform but outside the subform.  The approach I show is easier to maintain.